# How to get chain ID from MetaMask using JavaScript async await

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

How to get result value out of async await function?
I am trying to get current chain ID in the MetaMask, I get object in return of the function.
I am expecting `0x4`, but it is not accessible outside of the function.

```
let account;
let currentChain;

const switchNetwork = async () => {
                currentChain = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_chainId' });
                console.log(currentChain + ' <- currentChain'); //for debug
                return currentChain; //tried
}

let fromCheck = switchNetwork();
console.log(fromCheck + ' <- fromCheck'); //for debug, expecting `0x4`
```

Result:

```
[object Promise] <- fromCheck
0x4 <- currentChain
```

Object looks like this:

```
Promise {<pending>}[[Prototype]]: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: "0x4"
0x4 <- currentChain
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a value out of a promise (the return type of an async function), you must use either `.then(value => { ... })` or `await`.

In your specific case, this would look like:

```js
let fromCheck = await switchNetwork();
console.log(fromCheck + ' <- fromCheck');

// or

switchNetwork()
    .then(val => {
        console.log(val + ' <- fromCheck');
    });
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules (at ?chain=173:227:25)` I attempted that also earlier. Got it for `let fromCheck = await switchNetwork();`

Comment: yes, you can only use await inside of async functions. since you're not using modules, you need to create a temp async function, something like main() to hold the await, or just use .then()